# Join two IOs with - in haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I need to join two `IO String`s with a `-` in between. Here's what I came up with, which works - what's the right way?

```
import System.Environment
f :: String -> String -> IO String
f x y = (foldl1 (++)) <$> sequence [(getEnv x),(return "-"),(getEnv y)]
```

Comment: Are you sure that works the way you want? Looks essentially equivalent to `f x y = getEnv x` (up to some nonsense with yours throwing extra exceptions, perhaps) to me.

Comment: no it doesn't. fixed.

Comment: even uglier now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could here use an applicative style function:

```
f :: String -> String -> IO String
f x y = withHyp <$> getEnv x <*> getEnv y
    where withHyp ex ey = ex ++ '-' : ey
```

So here we join the two `String`s that are then joined with a hypen in the middle through the `withHyp` function.

Or for a list of environment variables that we need to fetch, we can use `mapM` and perform an `intercalate`:

```
import Data.List(intercalate)

f :: [String] -> IO String
f xs = intercalate "-" <$> mapM getEnv xs
```

Answer (score 6):

I'll be honest, the idea behind your approach actually looks pretty sane to me. To start with, I'd probably use `concat` intsead of `foldl1 (++)`, and drop some parens, getting us to:

```
f x y = concat <$> sequence [getEnv x, return "-", getEnv y]
```

This really doesn't seem that bad to me. But if I really wanted to push farther, here's some thoughts I would have. First, I'd recall the `intercalate` function.

```
f x y = intercalate "-" <$> sequence [getEnv x, getEnv y]
```

There's a handy shorthand for applying a function to each element of a list, too; `mapM f = sequence . map f`. So:

```
f x y = intercalate "-" <$> mapM getEnv [x,y]
```

I would stop there; it looks quite clean and maintainable to me.

Comment: Just a note for OP about `concat`: `foldl1 (++)` for a 3 item list is evaluated as `(a ++ b) ++ c`, which is slightly slower than `a ++ (b ++ c)` due to traversing `a` twice. So `concat` is actually implemented as something more like `foldr (++) []` (give or take some differences in syntax)

Answer (score 4):

One way of joining two `IO String`s would be:

```
dash :: IO String -> IO String -> IO String
dash x y = do
    s1 <- x
    s2 <- y
    return $ s1 <> "-" <> s2
```

We "unbox" each of `x` and `y` to get the contained `String`s, then "rebox` them with a hyphen (using the analogy for Functors).

It can be shortened to:

```
dash = liftA2 (\s1 s2 -> s1 <> "-" <> s2)
```

Where `liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c` takes a binary function and "lifts" it into a binary function on `Applicative`s, which are a superset of `Monad`s.

Your `f` can then be implemented as `f x y = dash (getEnv x) (getEnv y)`.

Comment: change signature to match `String -> String -> IO String` please